# How do I create an Xfce application menu containing only the contents of one category?

Tags: xfce, application, .desktop

I want to create an application menu in Xfce that contains no submenus, rather just contains application launchers for all `.desktop` files in the `virtualization` category. If you are uncertain as to what I am referring to, please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

In this screenshot, if I had my way, there would be no virtualization submenu, rather "Arch Linux", "CentOS 7-1511", "Debian 8.2", *etc.* and all the other `.desktop` files for these VMs would be placed in the Virtualization application menu directly. I have written custom `.menu` files before, and I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/1.0/menu.dtd">

<Menu>
  <Name>Virtualization</Name>
  <Directory>xfce-virtualization.directory</Directory>
  <!-- Read standard .directory and .desktop file locations -->
  <DefaultAppDirs/>
  <DefaultDirectoryDirs/>

  <!-- Read in overrides and child menus from applications-merged/ -->
  <DefaultMergeDirs/>
  <!-- Virtualization Software-->
  <Include>
    <And>
      <Category>Virtualization</Category>
    </And>
  </Include>

  <Layout>
    <Merge type="menus"/>
  </Layout>

</Menu>
```

but it gave me an empty virtualization application menu.

Answer (score 2):

For the applications' shortcuts to be found, the `.desktop` files must be located in one of default directories, such as `~/.local/share/applications` for current user or `/usr/share/applications` for all users.

If you are unsure what went wrong in your case, check out my working example tested in Xubuntu 14.04 (Xfce 4.10) as below.

### Example setup

The following setup assumes that:

- the shortcuts (`.desktop` files) have been created and include at least one category, which could be existent (i.e. "System") or non-existent (i.e. "Custom", "Virtual");
- the shortcuts have been moved to the shared or local directory i.e. `~/.local/share/applications`;
- the menu (`.menu` file) have been created such that the shortcuts from particular defined category is included (i.e. "Virtual");
- the menu is placed somewhere appropriate i.e. `~/.config/menus` directory

The `.menu` file contains the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Menu
  PUBLIC '-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN'
  'http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd'>
<Menu>
    <Name>Parent</Name>
    <!--This defines where to find .desktop files-->
    <DefaultAppDirs />
    <!--This affects what entries will appear under "Parent"-->
    <Include>
        <Category>Virtual</Category>
        <Category>X-Xfce-Toplevel</Category>
    </Include>
    <!--This includes what entries will appear under "Child" -->
    <Menu>
        <Name>Child</Name>
        <Include>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        </Include>
    </Menu>
    <!--This affects how will the entries appear under "Parent"-->
    <Layout>
        <Menuname>Child</Menuname>
        <Filename>xfce4-about.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-file-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>vm-test.desktop</Filename>
    </Layout>
</Menu>
```

In this example, I have only created one custom shortcut named `vm-test.desktop` that will appear under "Parent" menu. The other `.desktop` files are already existing in `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` directories. I had included these on purpose, to show it works in both ways.

### Example screenshots

Add "Application Menu" applet to the Xfce panel, and select "Use custom menu file" and load the `.menu` file from the share or local directory. Finally, click on the menu applet to see the shortcuts.

[image: Xfce menu applet properties]

[image: Xfce menu applet demo]

### Discovering shortcuts

The shortcuts that have been added to `~/.local/share/applications` directory will also be found automatically by Whisker Menu or Applications Menu applet (using default `.menu` file).

The `.desktop` files, which specify non-existent category or do not specify any category, will appear under "Other" category. If it has several or more categories, it will appear in the existent category only i.e. "System" and does not appear under "Other".

To understand this, see the content of `.desktop` file I have used in example above.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=VirtualBox VM test
Comment=Run "test" VM in VirtualBox
Exec=virtualbox --startvm "test"
Icon=virtualbox
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Custom;System;Virtual;
Name[en_US]=VirtualBox VM test
GenericName=VM test
```

As such, the custom shortcut will appear under "System" category in Application Menu based on the specified categories. Additionally, because it has specified "Virtual" category, the custom `.menu` file can easily include any `.desktop` files that have "Virtual" category.

### Additional notes

In Debian, there were no `.desktop` files by default in `~/.local/share/applications` and `~/.config/menus` directory does not exist (need to create this manually).

Tested working in Xubuntu 14.04 (Xfce 4.10) and Debian 8.3 Xfce (Xfce 4.10) 32-bit systems.

### References

- [Desktop Menu Specifications 1.0](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html) at Freedesktop.org.
- [howto:customize-menu](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/customize-menu) at Xfce Wiki.